# Filter 'belongsTo' results

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Im new in grails and its being a tough job try to understand it without someone who can ask this types of questions.
I have the following problem. This are two of my domain classes I have: *Pagadora* and *Calculo*

**Pagadora.groovy**

```
class Pagadora {
     String nombre
     Boolean activo
     static hasMany = [calculoIMSS: Calculo, calculoPagado: Calculo, calculoConvenio: Calculo]
     static mappedBy = [calculoIMSS: 'imss', calculoPagado:'pagadoPor', calculoConvenio:'convenio']
}
```

the Boolean variable *activo* refers if the "Pagadora" will gonna show up in the "select list" of the view in the class Calculo

**Calculo.groovy**

```
class Calculo {
    String nombre
    BigDecimal sueldo
    static belongsTo = [imss:Pagadora, pagadoPor:Pagadora, convenio:Pagadora]
}
```

What I want is the following, i want to filter in the select, only the Pagadoras that are active

```
 <g:select id="imss" name="imss.id" from="${Pagadora.Pagadora.list(sort: "nombre", order: "asc")}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${calculoInstance?.imss?.id}" class="many-to-one form-control" noSelection="['':'-Escoja la empresa-']" />
```

Sorry If it was a little hard to understand me, but it was a little difficult for me try to explain something like this in english (my native language is Spanish :P)

Comment: This isn't really what your question is about but it isn't a great idea to embed code like that in the GSP.  Better practice is to execute the query before the view is rendered (usually in a controller action or a service method) and put the results in the model that is passed to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the entries that are active, change the `from` attribute to:

```
from="${Pagadora.findAllByActivo(true) [sort: 'nombre', order: 'asc']}"
```

This is a [dynamic finder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#finders).

[Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533584/jeff-scott-brown) points out in the comments that the boolean parameter here can be omitted (see examples for [findAllBy](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html)). If you want to get all the inactive entries, you could still do without the parameter by naming your finder `findAllByNotActivo`. This comes in especially handy when you have two parameters for your finder where one is a boolean.

Comment: Instead of `Pagadora.findAllByActivo(true)` you can shorten that to `Pagadora.findAllActivo()`.  I worked on some of that about 4 years ago for Grails 1.3.2.  https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6277

Comment: @Jeff: thanks, i thought so, but I was having trouble finding that in the documentation.

Comment: Right. There isn't a lot of detailed description of that capability in the user guide but there are examples.  For example, http://grails.org/doc/2.4.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html shows using methods like `Book.findAllPaperbackByAuthor("Douglas Adams")` and `Book.findAllNotPaperbackByAuthor("Douglas Adams")`.  The `paperback` property is the boolean being handled there.